# PDF Attachments sent from iOS Not Displayed Properly in Outlook Mail Client

Tags: iphone, ios, pdf, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller, outlook-2007

When I send an e-mail with a PDF attachment from an iOS device, the PDF attachment doesn't get displayed properly in the Outlook mail client. Here is how it looks like:

[image: Outlook can't display the attachment]

(The attachment PDF is actually sent, if you right click the e-mail and select 'View Attachments', then you will be able to view the PDF. However, with the red cross the customers think that the attachment wasn't properly attached.)

Here is the code that sends the e-mail:

```
MFMailComposeViewController* controller = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
controller.mailComposeDelegate = self;
[controller setToRecipients:@[@"test@test.com"]];
[controller setSubject:@"Subject"];
[controller setMessageBody:emailData.emailBody isHTML:YES];

[controller addAttachmentData:emailData.reportData mimeType:@"application/pdf" fileName:emailData.reportName];

[self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
```

There is a workaround: If you set the message body as not HTML (`[setMessageBody:isHTML:]`), then the attachment is correctly displayed in Outlook. However, this means that you can't properly format the e-mail text and also can't add any kind of HTML signature to the e-mail.

This problem occurs with iOS7; I can't remember too well but I think the attachments were fine in iOS6.

Is it possible to have the e-mail HTML formatted and have the PDF attachment looking good in Outlook? Is the problem at the e-mail creation part or more at the Outlook side? The other e-mail clients (Gmail or Yahoo) seem to be handling this well.

Comment: You have set the pdf mime type, but not file extension. Does changing that fix the issue?

Comment: Isn't file extension part of filename? I set the filename as xxx.pdf.

Answer (score 1):

We were working on the same issue and our team spent all day on this one today. One thing that we discovered today is that if the PDF only has one page, it will cause the the error. However, when we added a second blank page to the PDF, then the PDF came through properly as an attachment.

It looks like Outlook is trying to display a single page PDF inline rather than as an attachment. If you add the second page, it worked fine.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks Keith. Yes, inlining the PDF seems to cause a lot of problems. Unfortunately, I have no control over how many pages the PDF will be. But, this explains why some users experience the problem while others don't!

Answer (score 1):

Did you got reason why PDF attach as in-line instead normal attachment in email?

**Know When Mac OS X Mail Will Show a PDF Inline, When as an Icon**

To know whether Mac OS X Mail will display a PDF file attachment as an icon or inline, look at the file's length:

- PDF files of only one page are displayed inline in the message text.
- PDF files with two or more pages are shown as icons.

For the single-page PDF files, you can switch between inline and icon display by selecting View as Icon or View in Place from the context menu respectively. To open the context menu, click on the PDF (shown inline or as an icon) with the right mouse button, click with the left mouse button while holding down Ctrl or tap with two fingers on the trackpad while the mouse cursor is over the PDF.

Answer (score 1):

The following works for me:

```
    // Should octet-stream be more specific for a PDF file?
    // YES: It seems that earlier (was this iOS6 or iOS7, before iOS7.1?) that the PDF icon showed up properly with just the @"application/octet-stream" and the fileName having .pdf. However, just now (3/30/14), with iOS7, the PDF icon only showed up when I changed the MIME type to @"application/pdf"
    [email addAttachmentData:data
                       mimeType:@"application/pdf" // @"application/octet-stream"
                       fileName:justFileName];
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this http://email.about.com/od/macosxmailtips/qt/et080506.htm

- PDF files of only one page are displayed inline in the message text.
- PDF files with two or more pages are shown as icons.

Comment: Thanks for the link, made me learn about the Attachment Tamer.

Answer (score 0):

I've been working the same problem myself and I've been having all sorts of problems (blog post to my users at https://easybooksapp.com/blog/media-types-for-pdf-attachments).

For most people it's fine, the PDF appears in their mail client fine. But for some mail clients such as Outlook and when viewing Gmail in Chrome I see the same error you're seeing. The attached PDF appears as a broken image, despite the attached file being sent as the correct MIME type (application/pdf). I narrowed this down to a problem in how the Mail app on iOS encodes the attachment when the user has an HTML signature set in their iOS Mail settings. If their signature includes an embedded image (the image data is included in the message) this causes the problem. When users delete their signature and replace it with a plain text or simple html signature it's all fine!

Today I was about to start working on finding out the differences between how OS X and iOS send the mail, as under OS X the mail is received okay. I just repeated the same tests today to discover the problem seems to have gone away in iOS 7.1. To confirm it I've repeated the exact same steps on an older iPad that still has iOS 7.0 and the problem exists as before.

So it looks like it was in fact an iOS problem in the end.

CORRECTION:
I've updated the iPad from iOS 7.0 to 7.1 and the problem still exists. I will have to do some more work to find out what the difference in encoding is between OS X and iOS 7.

Answer (score 0):

Use text/pdf instead of application/pdf.